# what is the correct syntax of BLPOP on Predis?

Tags: php, syntax, redis

I do it like this:

```
$r = new Predis\Client($single_server, $options);
$retval = $r->blpop('queue:query');
```

But I get this error:

`ERR wrong number of arguments for 'blpop' command`

Whenever I do this

```
$r = new Predis\Client($single_server, $options);
$retval = $r->blpop('queue:query',0);
```

I get the error:

`Error while reading line from the server`

Doing it from **redis-cli**

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> BLPOP queue:query
(error) ERR wrong number of arguments for 'blpop' command
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> BLPOP queue:query 0
1) "queue:query"
2) "hello world"
```

Comment: Have you tried `$r->blpop(array('queue:query', 0))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bug. The [latest](https://github.com/nrk/predis/zipball/v0.6.6-PHP5.2) version doesn't have this issue, also it apparently dropped namespaces:

```
<?
include_once "Predis.php";

$r = new Predis_Client();
$retval = $r->blpop('queue:query',0);
var_dump($retval);
?>
```

It blocked when I accessed the page. Then, I issued `LPUSH queue:query 0`, went back to the page, and got this:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(11) "queue:query" [1]=> string(1) "0" }
```

Nevertheless, I would recommend the use of [phpredis](https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis), it is faster than this library, because it is compiled as a php extension. If you have the rights in your server, that's a good pick.